# Import a txt file with negative numbers but the minus is the last char

Tags: php, sql, regex, txt

I have to import a txt file in my SQL database but the negative numbers are written with minus at the end (for ex : 11.719,88- or 13.791,47-).

When I import, negative numbers are positive. All my calcultate datas are false...

In my preprocess function (php), I tried many way to manage it but no success.
Here is my function :

```
$char = $row['column_numbers'];
$char_array = str_split($char);
$last_char = end($char_array);
if($last_char == '-'){
    $char_array = preg_replace('/[-]/', '', $char_array);
    $char_array = '-'.$char_array;
    return $char_array;
}else{
    return $char_array;
}
$row["column_numbers"] = $char_array;
```

And I have also this message php :
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion

What am I do wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: Not being a willing php participant, can you explain what this `$char_array = preg_replace('/[-]/', '', $char_array);` is doing ? Is it taking each individual array element, replacing with regex, then assigning to a temp array to be copied to and overwrite the original array ?

Comment: And can you concantenate a string to a character array ? `'-'.$char_array;`

Comment: This is simple string manipulation, and there's no need to get arrays or regular expressions involved. Try looking at `substr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted, string functions are sufficient here; specifically `substr()` and `rtrim()` come handy:

`substr($col, -1)` gives us the last character and `rtrim($col, '-')` helps to remove the last character.

```
function fixNegatives($col) {
    if(substr($col, -1) == '-') {
        return '-' . rtrim($col, '-');
    }else{
        return $col;
    }
}
```